# Replace out of range date with null

Tags: c#

I'm reading in utility billing information from an EDI file which contains reading start and end dates, amongst other things.

Before I write my various records to my database I am taking the EDI object and transforming it into my database model using the following method:

```
var invoices = EdiReader.EdiReader.ReadEdiAndConvert(filePath);    
var invoicesForSite = invoices.Where(x => x.SiteNo == site);    
List<DbBillInvoice> dbBillInvoices = new List<DbBillInvoice>();

    foreach (var invoice in invoicesForSite)
       {
          var newInvoice = new DbBillInvoice()
          {
            ...
            MeterNumber = invoice.MeterNumber,
            StartReadDate = invoice.StartReadDate,
            StartRead = invoice.StartRead,
            StartReadType = invoice.StartReadType,
            EndReadDate = invoice.EndReadDate,
            EndRead = invoice.EndRead,
            EndReadType = invoice.EndReadType,
            ...
          };

            dbBillInvoices.Add(newInvoice);
       }    
            return nPowerBillInvoices;
```

In the EDI file format, it seems records that shouldn't have a `StartReadDate` or `EndReadDate` are coming in as `{01/01/0001 00:00:00}` rather than null, then when I try to do the write to the table I receive the following:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

I think this is because the default and lowest value for `DateTime` is `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`

I've made the two date properties nullable now however I need to somehow convert these properties to be null rather than what they come in as when the date is not something meaningful.

I have tried doing the following:

```
StartReadDate = billInvoice.StartReadDate == default(DateTime) 
  ? null 
  : billInvoice.StartReadDate;
```

However I soon realised that the default DateTime value in .Net is 12 hours ahead of this EDI value so nothing matches this condition.

**How can I capture these bad dates and replace them with null**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var badDate = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);

return EdiReader.EdiReader.ReadEdiAndConvert(filePath)
    .Where(x => x.SiteNo == site)
    .Select(invoice => new DbBillInvoice() 
    {
        MeterNumber = invoice.MeterNumber,
        //assuming invoice.StartReadDate is actually a DateTime value, and not a string,
        // and that DbBillInvoice.StartReadDate is Nullable<DateTime>
        StartReadDate = (invoice.StartReadDate == badDate)?(DateTime?)null:invoice.StartReadDate,
        StartRead = invoice.StartRead,
        StartReadType = invoice.StartReadType,
        EndReadDate =  (invoice.EndReadDate == badDate)?(DateTime?)null:invoice.EndReadDate,
        EndRead = invoice.EndRead,
        EndReadType = invoice.EndReadType,
        ...
    }).ToList(); //Potential for a big performance win if you can change processing to avoid the ToList() call here.
```

Comment: It is indeed a DateTime? value and not a string

Comment: I will only acknowledge answers from people with Half Life related avatars from this point onwards

Comment: Nice avatar, where'd you get that idea from?  ;)

Comment: I've used this avatar since 2008

Comment: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'DateTime'

Comment: Should I put (DateTime?) before the null in the ternary operator lines?

Answer (score 1):

In **.NET**, `DateTime` is a `struct`.  This means that it cannot be `null`. You can wrap it as a `Nullable<T>`, i.e.; `Nullabel<DateTime>` or simply `DateTime?`.  This will allow it to `default` to `null`.

Otherwise, if you're not able to change the properties defined in that class you could filter them out when iterating over them with a `.Where` clause.

```
var minimalMeaningfulYear = 1;
foreach (var invoice in 
             invoicesForSite.Where(i =>
                                   i.StartReadDate.Year > minimalMeaningfulYear &&
                                   i.EndReadDate.Year > minimalMeaningfulYear ))
{
    // Logic here for filtered invoices...
}
```

Comment: StartReadDate and EndReadDate are now nullable, so they can store nulls but the problem is that the EDI library is returning me populated DateTimes for every record whether they are meaningful or not, so I kind of want to say, if the year is '0001' for the billInvoice.StartReadDate, then set StartReadDate to null, but more syntactically.

Comment: There, the `minimalMeaningfulYear` is now "1". That means that '0002' and above are considered acceptable.

Comment: Also, every single record would drop into that loop with because value of ediDefault would be 1/1/0001 12:00:00 PM, and all my dates would either be { 01/01/0001 00:00:00 } or meaningful dates i.e != 1/1/0001 12:00:00 PM

Comment: Love the avatar ;P

Comment: Yes I know but its not likely that im going to get records coming in as 0002, I know my pseudo logic is flawed but its something along those lines im seeking.